# Using couchdbkit (3rd party library) on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloudant, couchdbkit

I'm having difficulty getting couchdbkit to function properly on Google App Engine.  I'm either not importing my libraries correctly or I've run afoul of [GAE's Python Sandbox rules](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox).  Anyone know if I need to include restkit when using couchdbkit on GAE (that's where some of the problems are coming from)?

Here's my configuration:

app.yaml
zapdome.py
couchdbkit/
restkit/

I've stripped zapdome.py to just the basics (connect to my CouchDB database server):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import urllib, httplib, datetime
from couchdbkit.schema.base import *
from couchdbkit.schema.properties import *
from couchdbkit.client import Server

USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

class QuoteEntry(Document):
    name = StringProperty()
    symbol = StringProperty()
    price = StringProperty()
server = Server('https://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + USERNAME + '.cloudant.com/')
```

These are the errors I'm logging:

```
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
Traceback (most recent call last):
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
  File "/base/data/home/apps/zapdome/1.350215157753999092/restkit/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
    from .client import Client, MAX_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
  File "/base/data/home/apps/zapdome/1.350215157753999092/restkit/client.py", line 21, in <module>
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
    from httplib import FakeSocket
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
ImportError: cannot import name FakeSocket
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
Traceback (most recent call last):
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.309
  File "/base/data/home/apps/zapdome/1.350215157753999092/couchdbkit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.310
    from .resource import  RequestFailed, CouchdbResource
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.310
  File "/base/data/home/apps/zapdome/1.350215157753999092/couchdbkit/resource.py", line 25, in <module>
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.310
    from restkit import Resource, ClientResponse
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.310
ImportError: cannot import name Resource
E 2011-05-05 20:39:31.310
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: 'import *' not allowed with 'from .' (__init__.py, line 159)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/zapdome/1.350215157753999092/zapdome.py", line 4, in <module>
    from couchdbkit.schema.base import *
```

Since it's choking on httplib.FakeSocket and restkit.Resource, I'm beginning to think I'm going outside the bounds of what GAE permits.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but it appears I was trying to do things outside the confines of [GAE's Python Sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox).  I think it took issue with the socket stuff.  The good folks at [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) pointed me to [this Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Heroku-equivalent-for-Django-applications) that lays out more liberal hosting options for Python/Django.

BTW, I went with [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) and got everything working fine within an hour and I'm definitely no sys admin (but they do not offer a free hosting solution).

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the problem looks to be import syntax rather than sandboxing rules. It's complaining because you're doing an import * from base, which then tries to import from .resource. Using import * with a relative module path is disallowed in Python 2.5.

You can try changing your import * to import only what you actually need, e.g. Document.

Comment: @Drew-Sears, excellent point but changing to:

'import urllib, httplib, datetime
from couchdbkit.schema.base import Document
from couchdbkit.schema.properties import StringProperty
from couchdbkit.client import Server'

yields the same error log.  I notice in couchdbkit/schema/__init__.py there's this:

'from .properties import *
from .base import *
from .properties_proxy import *'